# Global variable goes undefined on page refresh JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, undefined, page-refresh

I'm having an issue where my global variable for a counter is going undefined when refreshing page. Each time you navigate to another page it bumps the counter and it works fine... but as soon as you hit refresh it says "cannot read property 0 of undefined"

My code:

```
var answer = function(currAnswer){
    if(answer[index].getAnswer !== currAnswer){
        return false;
   }
   else {
       return true;
    }
}
```

It works fine until you refresh the page and then it complains about 0 being undefined? Index is the global var which is bumped up when navigating between pages...

This isn't best practice but I'm still confused as to what is happening?

Comment: `answer` is defined as a function, then you're trying to read it like an array (or associative array) - its entirely unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: it is normal that a refreshed page clears all of the variables, this is how it should work

Comment: @Saar what's weird is that when I console.log('index : ', index); it's giving me the correct index even after I refresh...

Comment: The code in your question does not seem to reflect what you're talking about. Please include where you are using `console.log` and where you are setting/using "counter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side library. A new page load (aka a refresh) starts everything over.  If you want to persist something across page loads, you could use:

1. The server/database to keep track of this for a particular user
2. A cookie
3. Local or Session storage
4. A query string on the URL

See this article for additional reading on the subject: http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/index.html

Comment: I'm setting it into my session but I think somewhere else is breaking it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)?

```
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
```